# Change Order of columns

Tags: gridview, auto-generate, autogeneratecolumn

I am using gridView. I have 4 auto generated columns and 1 generated by my self. Now the column which i have generated is displayed first and then the auto generated columns.
I want to display auto generated columns first then my generated column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for that you need to know the **datafield** (data item that you want to bound) and use either template or boundcolumns to accomplish that, like:

an auto generate column grid

```
<asp:GridView id="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
</asp:GridView>
```

a manually generate column grid

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="My First Column" DataField="myField1" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="My Second Column" DataField="myField2" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="My Third Column" DataField="myField3" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="My Fourth Column">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("myField4") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

You can use either a **BoundField** or a **TemplateField**, with the template you can do much more, create a dropdown instead of a Label, etc... in a **BoundField the output will always be a Label** and you can only format the string value using the .NET nomenclature like **{0:d}**

You have more pre-defined templates to use such as Checkbox, Button, Hyperlink, Command and Image.

Comment: I have to user AutoGenerateColumns="true" not false. I need auto generated. but also want manually generated.

Comment: you can't have both... if you set up as AutoGenerateColumns="true" there is no control on the columns except from your Object Entity